Formatting variable subscript when it's text
I have a doubt about formatting the subscript of a variable. I'm following this convention: when the subscript is a text, or a letter which abbreviates a text word, I format the subscript as text.
Example: the variable X referred to a leakage is written like
X_{\text{leakage}}


or
X_{\text{l}}


Know comes the problem: I'm writing the document in portuguese. In my country (Brazil), foreign words must be, in general, emphasized. So the word "leakage", when in text mode in my document, is written like
\emph{leakage}


Should I emphasized it when in the subscript of a variable?
Example: the variable X referred to a leakage would be written like
X_{\text{\emph{leakage}}}


or
X_{\text{\emph{l}}}


I'm using the packages amsmath and mathtools.
For those who answer, I ask, if you have, some references about which convention I should use.
Edit: Mico put forward a convincing argument for continuing to use the subscript in normal text mode. But I also want to thank David, who gave me a reason for using \mathrm{...} instead of \text{...}.

You ask, "Should I emphasize [a foreign word] when [it occurs] in the subscript of a variable?" No. It's no longer a standalone word in text mode. Instead, it's part of a mathematical term, in math mode.

for italic for foreign words you should use \textit{...} not \emph{...} (you want to italicize them not emphasise them.  \textit would also work in math, but in general it is best to avoid \text... commands in math, and also I would not follow the convention of italisizing foreign words in math that is too confusing so I would use X_{\mathrm{leakage}}

@DavidCarlisle, why do you say for using \mathrm instead of \text? I'm still organizing the conventions I'll adopt. In many places I've seen people recommending \text over \mathrm. Off topic: how do you type the \cdots-like here on Stack Overflow?

@Mico, you have a point. Maybe you convinced me. Obs.: thanks for the "corrections" you made inside brackets. Such elegant, I'd say.

In math you normally want a fixed font for a fixed meaning, from the fonts set up for the current mathversion.  X_{\text{leakage}} does not use math fonts for the subscript it uses the font current in the text preceding the current math, so will use a roman font normally (but not necessarily the font used for \mathrm but would be an italic font in a theorem (but not necessarily the font used for \mathit)  . \text is for fragments of text eg in a display math \[x^2 > 0 \text{ as  $x$ is real } \]

I typed ...  just as three full stops in a code block (back ticks) \...``

Thank you all, guys. You helped me with my doubt and even with other good practices I'll follow from know on. Appreciate your prompt response.

For italic for foreign words you should use \textit{...} not \emph{...} (you want to italicize them not emphasise them. \textit would also work in math.
But in general it is best to avoid \text... commands in math, and also I would not follow the convention of italisizing foreign words in math that is too confusing so I would use X_{\mathrm{leakage}}
In math you normally want a fixed font for a fixed meaning, from the fonts set up for the current mathversion. X_{\text{leakage}} does not use math fonts for the subscript it uses the font current in the text preceding the current math, so will use a roman font normally (but not necessarily the font used for \mathrm but would be an italic font in a theorem (but not necessarily the font used for \mathit) .
\text is for fragments of text eg in a display math
\[x^2 > 0 \text{ as  $x$ is real } \]


I would argue sematically: If it's (an abbreviation of) natural language text, it should be \text, if it's a mathematical symbol, it should be \mathXY.

@Lupino yes but in a subscript it is almost never the former. Although there is an issue if using OT1 math fonts and not writing in english that text accents don't work in \mathrm
